# div displays behind iframe only when iframe contains SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, cross-browser

I'm building an offline solution which takes SVG and embeds it onto a webpage then manipulates the colors, etc. of the SVG elements.

Until IE10 came out, I was grabbing this SVG from the local folder with AJAX then writing it back into the page which pulls it into DOM and everything works fine.
Once IE10 came out, though, they have security around using AJAX on local files that had been described as "works as designed."  Changing any kind of security settings around the folders and browser is not an option.

The good news is I found a solution online where you create an iframe and set its source to the SVG you want to pull in (set as variables path and file here):

```
<iframe class="' + eN + '" src="' + path + file + '" width="' + w + '" height="' + h + '" style="border:0;z-index:1;display:none;"></iframe>
```

**EDIT**
I was needlessly complicating things here.  The crux of the problem is that I can float an absolutely positioned div overtop of an iframe fine unless that iframe contains an SVG.

**Another EDIT**
I think this is only occurring when running the page locally and not on a server.

**YET ANOTHER EDIT**
If I save the SVG as an XML file and load that, the div displays overtop of the iframe.  It seems like it's only an SVG thing.

Not sure if there's a way around this.

Comment: Have you tried inserting any "standard" content in the iframe (say, any external website)? If so, does it behave the same?

Comment: No, actually, the overlay shows up fine if I replace the iframe with an external website.

Comment: Do you have any SVG filters in your image? If so, remove them temporarily and see if the issue is fixed.

Comment: that doesn't work either.  I've tried appending the div to the body after all of the subdoc coding was done also and it still appears behind the svg.